# How can we find out the number of times the while loop lasted

Tags: java, while-loop

```
while((MAP = inputFile.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(MAP);
}
```

How can we find out the number of iterations performed by the while loop? In this textfile, they can be sometimes 5 lines of data, or 100 lines of data..If they are 5 lines, the while loop probably performed 6 loops. I want that number.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable external to the while loop to be a counter, and then increment the counter in the while loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
int count = 0; 
while((MAP = inputFile.readLine()) != null) { 
    System.out.println(MAP); 
    count++;
} 
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int iterations = 0;
while((MAP = inputFile.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(MAP);
    iterations++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
while((MAP = inputFile.readLine()) != null) {
    i++;
    System.out.println(MAP);
    // Some other stuff
}
System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to 0 before the while loop and increment the variable inside the while loop.  Output the variable after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why do it yourself if you can use `java.io.LineNumberReader.getLineNumber()` ?